# jython and lucene failed to get the standard module to create the StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, python, lucene, jython

I am trying to make use of apache lucene in jython27. To do so, I set the CLASSPATH:

```
% echo $CLASSPATH                                                                                                  
/opt/lucene-4.5.0/core/lucene-core-4.5.0.jar:/opt/lucene-4.5.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.5.0.jar:analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar:/opt/lucene-4.5.0/demo/lucene-demo-4.5.0.jar
```

I found [some](http://sujitpal.blogspot.de/2007/09/using-lucene-with-jython.html) [examples](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/overview-summary.html#overview_description) that I tried to follow. However, it failed to import the standard module to get the StandardAnalyzer().

```
>>> from org.apache.lucene import analysis
>>> dir(analysis)
['Analyzer', 'AnalyzerWrapper', 'CachingTokenFilter', 'CharFilter', 'NumericTokenStream', 'Token', 'TokenFilter', 'TokenStream', 'TokenStreamToAutomaton', 'Tokenizer', '__name__', 'tokenattributes']
>>> from org.apache.lucene.analysis import standard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name standard
```

Has someone an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ah damn.. I set the CLASSPATH wrong. This works:

```
% export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/lucene-4.5.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar
```